# F#, Import library, Visual Studio, offline. How?? Stanford NLP

Tags: f#, stanford-nlp

F#/ Visual studio pros, please help!

How to import libraries? Please just give me an example. How about java.io?

For Java I have tried to install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.JavaLanguageSupport)but didn't work.

[image: Problemz]

Comment: please don't link to sites that try to download files or extensions ... thanks

Comment: for your answer: .net libraries like the NUnit framework you seemt to be using are just referenced with "Add Reference" under your project settings. It's really the same as with C# or any other .net lang. in Visual Studio. As for Java: I know of nothing that let's you import Java-Namespaces/Assemblies but I don't really know anything about this (though I doubt that it's viable ... if only because of the many Java->.net rewrite)

Comment: I don't think you can use java references in a F# program.

Comment: By default, you can't use JVM libraries from .NET (or vice versa), but FWIW, there's something called [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net) that, supposedly, lets you do that anyway. I have no personal experience with IKVM, but from what I hear, it works, but is slow.

Comment: tqs, i gonna try it out and share it with you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the Stanford NLP libraries, these are available on NuGet and can be installed by right clicking on the project and selecting manage nuget packages. From there it's possible to add the references to the project. The .nuspec files which you've referenced in your project are for packaging up the libraries. So in your case, the nuspec filenames will be the thing that you search for in Nuget.

The Nuget website offers a guide for how to install packages [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)

Comment: Yeah agreed. Previously, without internet connection to my VM, I had to compile a lot of stuffs which hit lots of error. Out of frustration I complained and had the packages installed in colleagues local. Upon installation we will get DLLs (no manual compilation required anymore) in which we just need to add reference to when working with it. (For those who had the same trouble, we just need the DLLs, so locate it and transfer it to your offline workstation, also remember to download IKVMC, make sure you get the latest version!).

Answer (score 0):

.NET (which F# uses) and the JVM (which Java) uses are both managed code environments with many of the same capabilities.

But that are mutually incompatible.

While 3rd party tools might be able to bridge that gap (for at least simpler cases) there will be far more work to do that just referencing a `.jar` in Visual Studio.

Almost certainly better to use an equivalent .NET package (for IO look at the [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.IO) namespace (the necessary .NET assemblies should already be referenced).